# add content to the end of line

Tags: linux, awk, sed, linux-kernel

I want to add some content to the end of line. below is the example.

```
created by imagebuilder
default=0
fallback=1
timeout=0
hiddenmenu

title Amazon Linux 2016.03 (4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64 root=LABEL=/ console=tty1 console=ttyS0  
initrd /boot/initramfs-4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64.img
```

I want to add `transparent_hugepage=never` in the end of line which starts with kernel. Just like below

```
# created by imagebuilder
default=0
fallback=1
timeout=0
hiddenmenu

title Amazon Linux 2016.03 (4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64 root=LABEL=/ console=tty1 console=ttyS0 transparent_hugepage=never
initrd /boot/initramfs-4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64.img
```

How to do that using sed command. I tried many posts on the site but none is working in my case.

Comment: Tried... what exactly?

Comment: 1) find the line 2) add text. I'm sure both of these are googleable.

Comment: Why is the question tagged 'awk' when you specify sed in the question?

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/^kernel .*/& transparent_hugepage=never/' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

Comment: See: `man sed` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)